# What are these orange flowers growing in my father's garden?

Tags: identification, flowers

My father asked me to help him identifying these orange flowers that grow in his garden (located in the Eastern-Northern part of France). He told me that he thinks they are greasy plants and that they like poor soil. I attached two photos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to say "succulent" instead of "greasy"?

Comment: Sorry it is a translation mistake, appropriate term is "succulent". But I think he was confused by the leaves texture, when I look at the description of moss toss on internet is it said "herbaceous".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moss rose; Portulaca grandiflora. Comes in many colors ,easy cultivation , likes sun and relatively dry conditions.

Comment: And they reseed freely. I now have the prettiest melon patch in my state thanks to my having planted four of them 4 years ago.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: I've seen other flowers identified as moss roses, and I've never understood it.  This is the moss rose I knew growing up as a kid, I recognized it immediately.